# How can I modify my code to export(fstream) the info/output to csv/text file instead of a screen?

Tags: c++

Basically I wrote a pretty big calendar program and I need to change the output so that it is a text file/csv. Is there any way to do that? I can put my code in for reference, but I'm asking a general question.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


int GetFirstDay(int year);
int dayNumber(int day, int month, int year);
void displayMonthDays(int month, int numDays, int year);

int main()
{   

    ofstream out_file("output.txt");

        int year, numDays;
        int month = 1;
        int dayOfWeek;
        cout << "Enter year: ";
        cin >> year;
        out_file << "\n\n";

        int First_Day = GetFirstDay(year);
        while (month <= 12) {
            switch (month) {
                //Body
            case 1:
                numDays = 31;
                out_file << "January" << endl;
                break;
            case 2:
                if (((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0)) { numDays = 29; }
                else { numDays = 28; }
                out_file << "February" << endl;
                break;
            case 3:
                numDays = 31;
                out_file << "March" << endl;
                break;
            case 4:
                numDays = 30;
                out_file << "April" << endl;
                break;
            case 5:
                numDays = 31;
                out_file << "May" << endl;
                break;
            case 6:
                numDays = 30;
                out_file << "June" << endl;
                break;
            case 7:
                numDays = 31;
                out_file << "July" << endl;
                break;
            case 8:
                numDays = 31;
                out_file << "August" << endl;
                break;
            case 9:
                numDays = 30;
                out_file << "September" << endl;
                break;
            case 10:
                numDays = 31;
                out_file << "October" << endl;
                break;
            case 11:
                numDays = 31;
                out_file << "November" << endl;
                break;
            case 12:
                numDays = 31;
                out_file << "December" << endl;
                break;
            }
            displayMonthDays(month, numDays, year);
            out_file << endl;

            month++;
        }
   
    


}

// 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
// 8 9 ...
// dayOfWeek == 2
// _ 1 2 3 4 5 6
// dayOfWeek == 4
// _ _ _ 1 2 3 4
// d = j - dayOfWeek + 1;

void displayMonthDays(int month, int numDays, int year) {
    ofstream out_file("output.txt");

    int dayOfWeek = dayNumber(1, month, year);
    out_file << " S  M  T  W  T  F  S " << endl;
    out_file << "---------------------" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        if ((i * 7 + 1 - dayOfWeek) > numDays) {
            break;
        }
        for (int j = i * 7 + 1; j < (i + 1) * 7 + 1; j++) {
            int d = j - dayOfWeek;
            if (d >= 1 && d <= numDays) {
                out_file << " " << setw(2) << left << d;
            }
            else {
                out_file << "   ";
            }
        }
        out_file << endl;
    }
}


int dayNumber(int day, int month, int year)
{

    static int t[] = { 0, 3, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5, 1,
                    4, 6, 2, 4 };
    year -= month < 3;
    return (year + year / 4 - year / 100 +
        year / 400 + t[month - 1] + day) % 7;
}


int GetFirstDay(int year) {
    int century = (year - 1) / 100;
    int y = (year - 1) % 100;
    int weekday = (((29 - (2 * century) + y + (y / 4) + (century / 4)) % 7) + 7) % 7;
    return weekday;

}
```

I've tried using the outfile method, then outfile and myfile. The second time I did this I got nothing on the screen but couldn't see a text file downloaded anywhere. Finally, I tried replacing all the couts with outfile, like this:

```
out_file << "This will be in the .txt file" << endl;:
```

Any idea how I can modify my whole code to export as a csv/text file? Thank you!

Edit: I just edited it to show my most recent attempt. In this attempt, it doesn't send the .txt file anywhere so I'm assuming it hasn't exported.

Comment: Like you said replace `cout` with `out_file`. Did that not work for you?

Comment: If you have some code that doesn't work (i.e. the version that tries to write to a file) then why are you showing us the code that does work? If you have code that doesn't work then post **that** code, not some different code that does work.

Comment: First, move everything that outputs data to functions. Add a `std::ostream&` parameter to those functions and use that instead of `std::cout` when you output. Pass either `std::cout` or a `std::fsream` to the functions depending on where you want the output to go. You may end up with multiple output functions if you want to also switch between human readable and csv output.

Comment: hi @john, I replaced every cout with an out_file, and it looks like it works but I can't find the .txt file anywhere. I've looked everywhere and I don't think it exported it?

Comment: @john I see what you're saying, I realized now I should be posting my most recent code, I'll edit my question right now.

Comment: @Salty_Potato_Fries OK I can see the problem, I'll write up an answer.

Comment: *"I can put my code in for reference"* -- please don't. Well, post code, but not your real code. You are asking a general question, so a general example is more appropriate than your real code. Keep it simple. How much more than `int main() { ofstream out_file("output.txt"); out_file << "January\n"; }` do you need to demonstrate the general issue?

Comment: @JaMiT I put my code in because unlike all the other examples I saw on the internet mine was really big and in 3 parts, so I wanted to know if the mistake I made was something to do with that, the fact that I maybe didn't use the right command enough times.

Comment: @Salty_Potato_Fries *"really big and in 3 parts"* -- if this is essential to the problem -- if the simpler example is not sufficient -- then expand the simple example to have three parts, as in `void displayMonthDays() { ofstream out_file("output.txt"); out_file << "---------------------\n"; } int main() { ofstream out_file("output.txt"); out_file << "January\n"; displayMonthDays(); }` Hmm... I don't see the third part relevant to output. Well, should be OK. There are not many issues that can be shown with three parts but not with two. Anyway, the point is *Simplify!* (but keep the error).

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but this code doesn't need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does; `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: @john first of all, thank you so much for the explanation! Everything you said made a lot of sense. I did get a "build failed" error message which kind of confused me, do you mind if I ask something? First, I got an underline on void displayMonthDays, the 9th line of my code. It says that the function definition for displayMonthDays couldn't be found.  Should I just delete this line? It also says that int dayOfWeek is not initialized. I could just use int dayOfWeek = 1 and that should fix that right? Second, should I replace all my other out_file with just out? The ones where I ask the cases?

Comment: @JaMiT I was having an issue with the displayMonthDays on line 9, should I create a new identifier for it and add { ofstream out_file("output.txt"); out_file << "---------------------\n"; } in it?

Comment: @Salty_Potato_Fries Near the top of your program you have this `void displayMonthDays(int month, int numDays, int year);` This is called a *function prototype*. Now if you make a change to the actual function (like adding a new parameter) then you must also make the same change to the function prototype.

Comment: @Salty_Potato_Fries You can call your variables what you like, and just because a variable is called one thing in one function does not mean you have to use the same name in another function. The reason I changed `out_file` to `out` in the `displayMonthDays` is that in that function `out` is a generic output stream, it does not have to be a file output stream (it could be `cout` as I explained in my answer). But the compiler doesn't care about this, so call it whatever you feel most comfortable with.

Comment: @Salty_Potato_Fries Regarding `daysOfWeek`, if you are talking about the variable in `main` then as far as I can see that variable is not being used, so you could just delete it.

Answer (score 1):

So lets start with the good stuff

```
int main() {

ofstream out_file("output.txt");

    int year, numDays;
    int month = 1;
    int dayOfWeek;
    cout << "Enter year: ";
    cin >> year;
    out_file << "\n\n";
    ...
```

This is fine, creates a file called output.txt and writes to it.

Now let's see where it goes wrong

```
void displayMonthDays(int month, int numDays, int year) {
    ofstream out_file("output.txt");
    int dayOfWeek = dayNumber(1, month, year);
    out_file << " S  M  T  W  T  F  S " << endl;
    ...
```

Here you are creating **another** file called output.txt, so your program is trying to create multiple files called output.txt simultaneously. That's not going to work.

Instead you should pass the file you have already created as a parameter to `displayMonthDays`. Like this

```
void displayMonthDays(ostream& out, int month, int numDays, int year) {
    int dayOfWeek = dayNumber(1, month, year);
    out << " S  M  T  W  T  F  S " << endl;
    ...
```

(Here I've called the variable `out` but it's a variable, you can call it what you like).

Then when you call `displayMonthDays` you pass the parameter from `main`

```
        displayMonthDays(out_file, month, numDays, year);
        out_file << endl;
```

Where this file will appear is not something I can predict. It depends on your platform. If you want it to appear in a specific place then you can give a full name, including the directory where you want it to be created.

Finally note that you can use this function with any output stream, including `cout`, so this is perfectly OK, if you want to go back to using `cout`.

```
        displayMonthDays(cout, month, numDays, year);
        cout << endl;
```